# Qual camada da aplicação é voltada para processamento de regras de negócio mais amplas e complexas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-pattern

Estive lendo algumas perguntas e respostas sobre o padrão MVC e vi que dizem ser correto o tratamento de regras de negócio na camada `Controller`, como por exemplo: Verificar se um registro já existe no banco de dados antes de persisti-lo.

Porém, ainda tenho algumas dúvidas, e uma delas é referênte a tratamentos/regras de negócio mais complexas, que necessitam de mais classes para manter uma boa estrutura, como apuração de tributações e outros processamentos que compõem classes mais complexas.

Esse tipo de situação eu acredito que merecem uma outra camada de aplicação e gostaria de saer qual camada é essa?

Acredito não ser uma classe da camada de modelo por não se tratar de validação de dados, mas de processos.

Essa linha de raciocínio está correta? Se sim, qual seria a camada adequada para condicionar tais classes de processos mais profundos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não indicaria criar os métodos de negócio no controller do MVC. É muito comum você precisar expor esses métodos através de um serviço web, ou utilizar as mesmas regras de negócio em uma aplicação desktop, por exemplo. O ideal seria criar uma camada específica para tratar regras de negócio, desta forma sua camada pode ser reaproveitada em outros projetos da sua solução. Imagine que você desenvolva dentro do controller alguma regra que pode ser utilizada em outros controllers. Não seria muito elegante um controller acessar o outro.

Comment: Olá @Gus, obrigado pela sua resposta. E quais poderiam ser os nomes dessa camada com regras de negócio?

Comment: @James onde eu trabalho costumamos a colocar da seguinte forma. NomeEmpresa_Produto_Camada. Você pode chamar de RegraNegocio ou Negocio. A ideia é colocar um nome que represente o que você está propondo. Um nome sugestivo.

Comment: Negócio (Business) realmente aparenta ser o mais adequado. Vou apenas esperar um pouco mais para ver se surgem mais respostas. Grato por sua resposta!

Comment: Eu também tenho preferência por esse tipo de nomenclatura, o porém é que sua solução, se já não tem, pode vir a ter uma aplicação para dispositivos móveis, o que pela lógica receberia uma nome de camada **App**.

Comment: @Gus, é fora de escopo mas gostaria de saber de você se conhece engenharia de software e se saberia me indicar um livro com boa didática e conteúdo para estudo de software para alguém que não sabe nada sobre o assunto ainda? Grato!

Answer (score 2):

## Acredito não ser uma classe da camada de modelo por não se tratar de validação de dados, mas de processos. Essa linha de raciocínio está correta?

Depende. Na pergunta você disse o seguinte:

> Estive lendo algumas perguntas e respostas sobre o padrão MVC e vi que dizem ser correto o tratamento de regras de negócio na camada Controller, como por exemplo: Verificar se um registro já existe no banco de dados antes de persisti-lo.

Reconheço que disse algo assim, mas nas respostas em que afirmei isso o banco de dados é gerido pelo Entity Framework, que seria o Framework que implementa um repositório completo.

Neste caso, o que o *Controller* faz é invocar os métodos do Entity Framework apenas, e não realizar o tratamento completo de um ciclo de validação.

A função de um *Controller* é, basicamente, harmonizar os fluxos de dados entre os vários componentes de uma aplicação. No caso específico de uma validação, este lugar é o *Model*.

### Como isso pode ser feito?

- Por Atributos;
- Implementando a interface [`IValidatableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

### Sobre validação de processos

Quando a lógica é recorrente (ou seja, quando ela é usada em mais de um *Controller*) a abordagem correta é usando um padrão de design chamado *Helper*.

#### O que é um *Helper*?

*Helper* é uma classe, normalmente estática, ou um método de extensão (que é sempre estático, portanto) que contém uma lógica recorrente a vários *Controllers*. Ele pode ser invocado a qualquer momento por qualquer *Controller*, podendo utilizar um contexto de dados (Entity Framework) ou um repositório (não-Entity Framework).

Nele você pode colocar isso que você chama de "validação de processo", com uma sequência complexa de passos, sem necessariamente colocar essa lógica em um *Controller*.

## Aproveitando

O @Gus disse o seguinte na resposta dele:

> É muito comum você precisar expor esses métodos através de um serviço web, ou utilizar as mesmas regras de negócio em uma aplicação desktop, por exemplo.

Isto é verdade, mas a ideia é que no MVC6 o programador escreva um *Controller* para todas as camadas de apresentação, como Desktop ou Serviço Web.

Há, de fato, uma limitação de um *Controller* MVC ser quase que estritamente para um projeto Web, mas isso deve ser simplificado no vNext.

(Até a data desta resposta, o vNext ainda não havia sido lançado oficialmente)

Answer (score -1):

Na minha empresa desenvolvemos com .NET WebForms e MVC, nos separamos em 3 camadas (3 projetos dentro de uma solução): o layout do site (design e tratamento de alguns parâmetros), a BLL (Business, a regra de negocio com a montagem e validação do
 CRUD e processos complexos, de uma entidade) e a DAL (Data access layer, que acessa o banco de dados) esta ultima camada é chamada somente pela BLL. Vantagens: organização e reaproveitamento de código, ex: posso fazer um WebService acessar a minha BLL.